# UIScrollview with Auto-Layout

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I'm struggling with UIScrollView for a while now.

"descriptionLabel" and "genresLabel" will increase height during runtime and the gap to actors will increase. So i need the scrolling functionality here to see the actors label.

I set the height of the contentView as a height-constraint equal to View with priority 250 and hoped that the height will increase automatically if needed.

In fact nothing happens and no scrolling is possible.

How can i automatically increase the contentView height in the auto-layout context?

[image: Storyboard]

Comment: Does your ContentView's height grows as your labels' heights become bigger?

Comment: i hope so because the actors label will go down if the others label height increases. so there must be an increase of the contentview's height too...

Comment: Please, look at my answer, I've just created test project for you

Comment: I already answer to this question here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19036228/uiscrollview-scrollable-content-size-ambiguity-xcode-5-ios-7-interface-builder/27227174#27227174

Comment: Maybe you can use an UITableView with two sections and a footer view for the first one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to make ContentView's height flexible so it should get increased and the scrollview's content size will increase accordingly. Have a look into attached screenshots. Increase the bottom label top constraint (which is 495) value the scrollview's content size will get increased automatically.

Here is the [Sample Source Code](http://speedy.sh/7XVBk/Sample.zip)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: First of all thanks for the screenshot explanation.
I removed my height constraint of the ContentView (to View) but it changes nothing. I even get the following error in my storyboard: "Scrollview has ambiguous scrollable content height".

Comment: I have uploaded the sample code please download and check

http://speedy.sh/7XVBk/Sample.zip

Comment: i added in your project the constraints mentioned in you screenshots. result is identically to my project. Error: "Scrollview has ambiguous scrollable content height"
So there must be a hight defined for the contentview?

Comment: In this video the contentView height is increased in storyboard during the design process. During my design process all the labels fit on the screen but it is possible that the label height increases dependent on the content. so if i set the height constraint on the contentview, the height is fixed for this view, right?

Comment: if your label height will increase then the content height also should get increased(coz its super view of labels) and then the scrollview will scroll.

Comment: thx, for you help!
my mistake was the missing bottom constraint of the last label.

Comment: ok great alteast upvote my answer i displayed that you have to set bottom constraint in last label.

Comment: I set the bottom constraint priority of the last label to 750 and the top constraint priority of the first label to 1000.  All the other labels in between have 1000-constraints to each other.
Despite this, my top label is not positioned to meet the top constraint. Maybe you know why this is happening?

Comment: can you post the screenshot?

Comment: solved. seems like an xcode bug. after restarting and play with some different color backgrounds it seems to work fine now. crazy day... :-o

Answer (score 1):

Is your Actors label, the last element on this View? If it is then fix both Actors: and asdfas... to top, bottom and left. Now, for bottom set 'Constant' as 'Use standard value'.Also fix topmost element(here maybe 'No network connection!') to top and set its 'Constant' as 'Use standard value'. 
Try this and let me know if it works!

I have tried what i have told you.Pasting images of the same. Hope it helps!
[image]

[image]

[image]
For Actors label constraints include:

[image]
and for asdfas label constrains are as shown in the following image:
[image]

Comment: Yes, actors label ist the last element of the view and the constraints are all set.

Comment: Thx, for you help! my mistake was the missing bottom constraint of the last label.

Answer (score 0):

Just check this [link](http://natashatherobot.com/ios-autolayout-scrollview/), just have to write this to add up content view height:-

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    {
        let scrollViewBounds = scrollView.bounds
        let containerViewBounds = contentView.bounds

        var scrollViewInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero
        scrollViewInsets.top = scrollViewBounds.size.height/2.0;
        scrollViewInsets.top -= contentView.bounds.size.height/2.0;

        scrollViewInsets.bottom = scrollViewBounds.size.height/2.0
        scrollViewInsets.bottom -= contentView.bounds.size.height/2.0;
        scrollViewInsets.bottom += 1

        scrollView.contentInset = scrollViewInsets
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to understand whats wrong with your layout, so I've created test project with a 2 growing labels, all works fine, maybe you will find out what's wrong in your constraints :)

https://www.dropbox.com/s/j8269c03b32gra5/scrollview-test.zip?dl=0

Build my project and click "More text" button to add text dynamically to labels in scrollview

Comment: Thnx for the testproject. I see that you set the contentview height bigger than the viewcontroller height. In my normal case that shouldn't be the case, only when the labelsize increases dramatically. So there should only be a scrolling if the lables don't fit to the screen size.

Comment: thx, for you help! my mistake was the missing bottom constraint of the last label.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I needed to add a bottom constraint to my last element in the page. More explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45396193/1450348)