# UIView with Auto Layout doesn't increase height inside UIScrollView

Tags: ios, autolayout

What I'm trying to do is have a page similar to following wireframe that all `UILabel`s height should dynamically change based on the text:

[image]

I currently have a `UIView` inside a `UIScrollView`. The issue is I can't get the `UIView` resize properly based on the its content, for example when description is long. The sample code can be downloaded from [here](https://github.com/maniramezan/AutoLayoutFun)

If not into the mood for code, here's the constraints and how it's setup:

[image]

I tried to use the approach mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30394520/1450348)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FINALLY, found the solution to it. Needed to remove any height constraint for `UIScrollView` and `contentView` and add a bottom constraint as shown below:

[image]

Updated the sample app with this change. Now the sample app works as expected.