# Scroll view's content inset is 0 but there is space at top of scroll view

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I have a scroll view that I set the contentInset of programatically like so:

```
scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero
```

When my view renders, however, there is space above the content in the scroll view. I have already set `adjustScrollViewInsets` to false on the parent view. If I set the top inset to a negative number, the content moves closer to the top of the screen. Any ideas why this is happening?

Here is an image (the contentInset in this image is UIEdgeInsetsZero):
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Have you seen this question : http://stackoverflow.com/q/19036228/468724 ?

Comment: Share the screenshot

Comment: I already have the proper constraints set on the scroll view.