# ScrollView not resizing properly

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview

I have a ScrollView embedded in my ViewController. Inside the ScrollView I have embedded a content view (UIView) which has a UIImage set to match the left, top and right of the ScrollView with a dynamic height that changes depending on the aspect ratio of an image that the user can load after the ViewController loads. There are three buttons all horizontally aligned in the content view and spaced evenly apart from each other.

When the user loads in a photo that is too big for the screen it should just resize the ScrollView and the content view appropriately to allow scrolling to see the buttons but instead it just bunches up the buttons at the bottom of the screen.

Here is how the buttons should look:
[image]

Here is what happens when the photo is too big:
[image]

Here are the constraints of the ScrollView:
[image]

Here is my resizing code:

```
let img : UIImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
            let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
            let multiplyNum = screenSize.width / img.size.width
            imageViewHeightConstraint.constant = (multiplyNum*img.size.height)
            imageView.image = img
```

Even when I try and change the ScrollViews height programatically to a very large number it still won't get any larger than the ViewController (no scrolling).

Constraints of ContentView:
[image]

Constraint of ImageView:

[image]

Constraints of first 2 buttons:

[image]

Constraints of last button:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to set all the constraints that completely define the vertical layout of all elements (top constraint for image, vertical space between elements and bottom constraint of last element), and try changing the priority of the content hugging or compression resistance of the elements.

**Edit:**

You can achieve that behaviour with this view hierarchy:

```
- UIView
  - UIScrollView
    - UIImage
    - UIButton
    - UIButton
    - UIButton
```

There is no necessity to add a container view if you set the constraints like this:

*scrollView:*

Leading, trailing, top and bottom constraints to `view` (all 0)

*inner views (horizontal):*

1. Leading constraint from `imageView` to `scrollView`
2. Trailing constraint from `imageView` to `scrollView`
3. Equal width from `imageView` to `view`

*inner views (vertical):*

1. Top constraint from `imageView` to `scrollView`
2. Height constraint of `imageView` (this constraint constant will change depending on the size of the image)
3. Horizontal space from `imageView` to `button1`
4. Horizontal space from `button1` to `button2`
5. Horizontal space from `button2` to `button3`
6. Bottom constraint from `button3` to `scrollView`

There is no necessity to change the priority of the content hugging or compression resistance of the elements.
I already check that it works in a project.

Comment: I have done this and still the ScrollView will not get any larger than the ViewController it sits in.

Comment: Oh! thats weird, I just achieved the desired behaviour with the same elements, can you edit posting the constraints of all elements?

Comment: Okay thanks I updated. Tell me if there's anything I missed :) @juanjo

Comment: It seems like you have a container view inside the scroll view, is it really necessary to have it? You can place the image view and buttons directly inside the scroll view, it would make things easier unless there is a good reason not to do so

Comment: I was having this problem without the container view http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19036228/uiscrollview-scrollable-content-size-ambiguity

Comment: That issue can be easily solved for your case, since you have an image view that takes the whole width of the screen you can set the leading and trailing constraints of the image to the scroll view and an equal width constraint of the image with the view of the controller, that 3 constraints fully define the horizontal layout