# Autolayout with Scrollview in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, scrollview, ios-autolayout

It's driving nuts...

I am using storyboard....but if it this can be done programmatically, I would change immediately

- I have a scroll view set to fill parents view (x and y)
- I add the scroll pin spacing handlers to the borders of the view (in
  all four of them)
- I add a button near the bottom with the constrains

When rotation occurs I'm unable to see my button.

I haven't found any example on how to correctly use scrollviews in xamarin, if anyone knows any example would be appreciated, I'm new with xamarin.  Thanks!

UPDATE: IOS-CLASSIC

Comment: Just please clarify:1.  Android or iOS? 2. XForms or Classic? It looks like it is iOS Classic. Just want to confirm

Comment: in IOS, CLASSIC, sorry and thanks!

Comment: I find designer in Visual Studio very buggy. I will check it in XCode

Answer (score 0):

Works with the following constraints
[image]

Also you can check 
[UIScrollView Scrollable Content Size Ambiguity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19036228/uiscrollview-scrollable-content-size-ambiguity)