# AutoLayout in Xamarin for scroll view

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin.ios

i have an issue that is driving me mad! I am trying out Xamarin for iOS app development. My issue is the do with auto layouts and constraints, i have a simple UIView inside a scroll view, i cant get this to resize on both ipad and iphone. The scroll view also leaves a margin above the view of constraints. Anyone had any issues with this?
[image]

Comment: I don't see any constraints. If you provide storyboard file I will take a look. Meantime check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40183459/autolayout-with-scrollview-in-xamarin/40186304#40186304 If it helps you can mark it as answer

Answer (score 0):

1 - Add constraint to the child UIView inside the scroll view: Bind Top, Left, Right and Bottom.

2 - Set fixed Height to the child UIView.