# Xamarin iOS Add Items to a ScrollView in the StoryBoard

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, storyboard

I'm very new to iOS development and am at a lost about using the `scrollview`. I'm trying to create a `vertically scrolling` page in the storyboard. I can do it all in code, but for some reason, in the storyboard designer, it doesn't seem to work.

I've created a view controller and set the simulated size to free form, with a height of 1500. I've then added a view. I've then added a scrollview. In the ViewController class I've set the `scrollview's frame to be 375x667` and the `content size to be 375x1500`. It scrolls without a problem.

I then add another view, and make it a subview of the `scrollview`.  Then I add a button to the storyboard designer at `coordinates x: 35 y: 1100`. When I build the app and display it on the simulator, the button doesn't appear.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here [is solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27227174/1558147)

Main idea: you need to add `UIView` as subview of `UIScrollView` and set all margin constraint to 0.

Than you add controls inside that `UIView`. Also you need to be sure you set all constraints that way so OS can understood total height and width of your content

For ex.: if you have 1 `UIButton` in your view you have to set its width, height and all 4 margins. If any of constrains is missing, Designer will tell you that width and/or height of your content is ambiguous.