# How to fix inequality constraint ambiguity in iOS storyboard?

Tags: ios, iphone, uiview, uistoryboard, uicontainerview

Below is a screenshot of my current view controller.

[image]

The problem I'm trying to solve is currently the container view text gets pinned to the top of that UIView.

I have it setup this way to on smaller devices it has a scroll view and this way it's easiest for me to visualize and layout the elements.

So my goal is to set a max height on that UIView/container view (on the left) to have a max height of 190px (since that is the tallest the content will ever be).

[image]

I tried the above solution but it gives me an error saying `inequality constraint ambiguity`.

My goal is to just have a max height of 190px and center that view horizontally and vertically.

How can I achieve this?

**EDIT**

Changing bottom space to manage subscription to = instead of >= produces the following.

[image]

Comment: Do "Manage subscriptions" and "More Info" have bottom constraints?

Comment: @Paulw11 Yes. More info to the bottom layout, and manage subscriptions to more info

Comment: Change the bottom constraint to "Manage Constraints" to = 20 instead of >= 20.

Comment: @Paulw11 just posted the error when I change it to = instead of >=

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can fix this ambiguity by placing a low priority height constraint on the View with the height = 190.

This will act as a placeholder height constraint which can be overriden by the higher priority <= 190 constraint anytime.