# How to set UIScrollView Height in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiview, uiscrollview

I'm using swift to build an application. I want to add some content to my view controller using storyboard.

I already put everything inside the scrollview and set the specific height, but however when I run the application, the scrollview always set longer than the button in the bottom of the view

I want the scroll view stop right after the button

Please kindly help me how to solve this problem

thank you

[image: this is the top of the view]

[image: after scrolling (see the blank content after button submit)]

after scrolling

for your information, please ignore the white space between 'critics' and submit button, because actually there's UITextView between them but not visible (still try to add some border)

these are my storyboard preview

[image: storyboard 1]

[image: storyboard 2]

Comment: scrollView height according to content ?

Comment: Swift 2 or Swift 3? Xcode version?

Comment: Scroll views are a bit hard to deal with since the advent of **autolayout**, so there's a few pitfalls (they don't "just work" out of the box like more concrete subclasses such as table views or collection views). Fortunately, there are also lots of tutorials and blog posts on the web. Search "UIScrollView autolayout".

Comment: @iDeveloper : Swift 3.0

Comment: @iOSGeek yes, according to content (I set the content using storyboard)

Comment: @christ2702 please screenshot your storyboard. Or show more code

Comment: @christ2702 But seriously, by the looks of your app, it looks a lot like a `UITableView` with custom cells would work perfect. Not usre how many rows of stars you have in total, but the reusing machinery of table views greatly helps performance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1) ScrollView Contraints

[image]

2) ScrollView -> contentView Constraints to scroll View same as above image

3) now ContentView width and Height Constraints to main View [SuperView in which ScrollView is embedded] and constraints will be as follows.

4) now click on the EqualWidth to View [Third constraint from top]and edit it as in step 6

[image]

5) contentView Width Contraint

[image]

6) ContentView Height Constraint // set priority [must] . here you need to change the first item and second item in the menu to as shown First as - ContentView.Height and second as - View.height and set priority to 250 after this a dotted line will appear in storyboard along the contentView

[image]

7) now add the content like [UIView, labels, textfields] in contentView and add constraints as Top upperMost view top space to contentView [like I have]DoubleRight imageView

[image]

and constraints for my DoubleRight imageView are

[image]

look for the Top space margin its given a top space 20 points

and same you need to do for the last item you will be adding in ContentView like I have uiView

[image]

add bottom space from this respective view to your superView[ContentView] and my constraints are:

[image]

after you had initialed all these steps results will be as Expected for every Screen size no need to change height additionally for screen sizes

Note : - [all the views must be connected to each other with top and bottom parameter]

like Flow will be

```
View1 - top to contentView and bottom to View2
View2 - top to View1 and bottom to view3
View3 [Last view] - top to View2 and bottom to contentView as shown
```

using uiView, uiimageViews their heights must be fixed

Comment: if still facing any issue feel free to ask

Comment: can I ask you something? using chat or whatever?

Comment: thank you very much, anyway can I have your contact or whatever?

Comment: check My modified answer I had explained all details if still you face an issue you can ask .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150063/discussion-between-ios-geek-and-christ2702).

Comment: @GenRiH, Thanks and Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

It may be helped

```
your_scrollView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 375, height: 667)
your_scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: 375, height: 1000) // You can set height, whatever you want.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

```
   your_scrollView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 375, height: 667)
   your_scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: 375, height: self.view.frame.size.hight)
```