# ScrollView is Not Appearing

Tags: ios, swift

Reference: [Add a ScrollView to existing View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36028493/add-a-scrollview-to-existing-view?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

I inserted a scroll view into an existing view and now my page is not appearing and I am not sure how to fix this. My scroll view is under the view so I do not understand why it is not displaying.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do not post pictures of code. Please copy and paste code as text into your question. Pictures can't be searched or referenced. They are harder to read and putting pictures on your question harder than copying and pasting text.

Comment: That red arrow next to your Login View Controller Scene is an indicator of problems with auto layout. Clicking it will show the ambiguities the layout engine finds. It's likely that your scroll view isn't displaying because it is missing constraints, and rendering zero height.

Comment: please check https://stackoverflow.com/a/45294116/6080920

Answer (score 1):

With auto-layout, the `UIScrollView` needs to be able to calculate its content size using the available constraints. This is often best accomplished by adding a `UIView` in the scroll view to act as the content view, rather than directly embedding `UIControl` subclasses. The content view can then be constrained to be equal width and/or equal height to the *parent* view of the scroll view. The variable height/width (depending on the scroll direction) of the content view can be calculated by fully constraining the widgets it contains.

Comment: Apple has some reference information about this here: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/WorkingwithScrollViews.html