# AutoLayout, put all views into a new parent view

Tags: ios, autolayout, storyboard

I had defined all views and had sets its constraints with `superview` in a view controller, but now I want to put all these children views into a `Scrollview`, I found all of these constraints disappear. Is there any good ways to make it easier to do, instead of reset all of these constraints?

Following the pictures showed on below:

[Origin constraints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zDYnk.jpg)

**Now, when I drag all these views into `ScrollView`, all constraints disappear**

[Missing all constraints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mr2Uk.jpg)

*(sorry these two links are screenshots, I don't have 10 reputation to post images)*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

simply select your UIElements which you want to be the child of UIScrollView.,
Now go to editor -> Embed In -> UIScrollView
Now your child viewcontrollers will be emebedded with scrollview with all constraints except the constraints which were dependent on its superview.
Here's a image of how to select and embed[image: Embed Elements]

The constraints which were dependent on superview layoutguide, you'll need to make them again with uiscrollview., add add constraint to scrollview with its superview.

Comment: That's the thing that OP is trying to avoid i.e. setting up the constraints that were dependant on the superview

Comment: As the question clearly specifies "I found all of these constraints disappear". So using this your all constraints will not disappear.., depending on their relativity... Even many of constraints will remain there only a few needs to add again @Malik

Comment: @ Er. Khatri Did you have a look at the screenshots shared by the OP?
The constraints that were removed were in fact the ones dependant on it's superview

Comment: Hi, Er.Khatri and @Malik . Finally, I solved this problem. I was using [UIScrollView Scrollable Content Size Ambiguity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19036228/uiscrollview-scrollable-content-size-ambiguity) to solve it. First, put a new view controller and put a scroll view, and then put a **view** into scroll view. Secondly, I copy children views from first controller into this **view**. Although, they will missing constraints which related to superview, but only need to add these constraints instead of reset all constraints. Thank you so much, both of you.

Comment: @YuanFu what you did is the same which xcode does for us.. if you have selected embed in -> View you would get a new view.. so always you can be  hassle free by letting xcode do the task for you. Well Kudos finally your problem is solved..