# ScrollView width constraint with fixed width views

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, ios-autolayout

I'm working on an app in XCode 10 with Swift 4. I have set up my view in storyboard for iPhone (wC, hR) in the following way:

- Scroll View (Top: superview, Bottom: superview, Trailing: Safe area, Leading: safe area)
- Inside the scroll view is a Container View: T,B,L,R to superview, equal width to base view (i.e. the screen)
- Within the container view are several labels and image views.

I have no issues with this setup.

The problem is when I make adjustments for iPad (wR, hR). Here I have disabled the trailing and leading constraints and instead added a width constraint of 690 and have aligned horizontally to superview. When I do this I get a constraint error that says "Ambiguous scrollable content width".

I believe the problem is that I'm aligning horizontally in relation to the superview which is the scroll view, and thus have no reference to the base view, but I'm not sure how to adjust this so it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'll need to use *two* "container" views.

for iPhone (wC, hR):

- scrollView -- Top: superview, Bottom: superview, Trailing: Safe area, Leading: safe area)
- "SuperContainerView" subview of scrollView -- Top/Bot/Lead/Trail to scrollView (the superView), equal width to **scrollView**
- "ContainerView" subview of SuperContainerView -- Top/Bot/Lead/Trail to SuperContainerView

Constraints on the subviews of ContainerView will control ContainerView's height, which will control SuperContainerView's height, which will control scrolling.

For iPad (wR, hR):

- Disable the ContainerView's Leading and Trailing constraints
- add a Width constraint of 690
- add a CenterX constraint to SuperContainerView

Results... Green is ContainerView, Blue is SuperContainerView (scroll view is inset 8 on each side):

[image]

[image]

[image]

If you want a max width of 690 when running on a phone rotated to landscape orientation, you'll need to do similar constraint modifications for wC, hC

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Although it doesn't make much sense, it could help if you also added align horizontal & vertical center constraints to the `Container View` (in regards to its `superview`, the `Scroll View`).

This is according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27227174/1147286) and my own struggles with AL.

Comment: Tried this suggestion but unfortunately didn't work. Thanks anyway.