# ScrollView with StackView and fixed footer outside

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, autolayout, footer, uistackview

Xcode 10, Swift 5 (this should be doable purely in the Storyboard)

The current layout:

```
- ChildView (child View of very first default view)
    - ButtonView
        - ScrollView
            - VerticalStackView
                - Button
                - Button
                - ...
    - FooterView
         - HorizontalStackView
            - Button A
            - Button B
```

What contraints do I need to always keep the Footer View at the bottom and make the `UIStackView` scroll behind it, while still maintaining a fixed height for each button in the `UIStackView`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This setup seems to attract multiple problems, from the buttons inside not being clickable (or `UITextField`s that can't be interacted with), to the `UIScrollView` not being scrollable or a "Content Size Ambiguity" error (described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19036228/2016165)) - just because a single constraint isn't set properly.

**The result:**

[image]

If there are less buttons that can all be displayed at the same time, it won't be scrollable but instead simply display the black background below the last button.

**How to get there:**

The constraints are set using the "add new constraints" button below the preview window.

[image]

*ChildView:*

- Trailing/Leading/Bottom: 0 to Superview
- Equal Height: to Safe Area:

  - Control-drag from the ChildView to the Safe Area and pick "Equal Heights"

*1. FooterView:*

- Trailing/Leading/Bottom: 0 to Superview
- Height: Equals 50
- Top to ButtonView:

  - Control-drag from the FooterView to the ButtonView
  - Choose "Top"
  - Click on the new constraint to open it in the inspector (FooterView.Top equals ButtonView.Bottom)

[image]

*2. ButtonView:*

- Trailing/Leading/Top: 0 to Superview
- Bottom to FooterView (already explained above)

*2.1. ScrollView (black):*

- Trailing/Leading/Bottom/Top: 0 to Superview
- The Bottom/Top constraints keep the ScrollView from "spilling over"

*2.1.1. VerticalStackView:*

- Alignment/Distribution: Fill
- Trailing/Leading/Bottom/Top: 0 to Superview
- Equal width to ButtonView:

  - Control-drag from the VerticalStackView to the ButtonView and pick "Equal Widths"
  - This disables the horizontal scrollbar of the ScrollView

*2.1.1.1. Button (gray):*

- Height: 50
- The VerticalStackView takes care of the rest

Of course you can also replace the buttons in the 'UIScrollView' with views to create some type of form.