# Scrollview has ambiguous scrollable content in xcode 11 using constraints

Tags: ios, swift

I have used ScrollView.  But I have updated my xcode 11 recently. When I add scrollView, it shows **Scrollview has ambiguous scrollable content** . Here is image adding constrant
[image]

After adding constraints it won't wrap or size according to the constraints. Here is the image
[image]

But I have used same thing in my project..What is the wrong please help me..

Comment: Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19036228/uiscrollview-scrollable-content-size-ambiguity

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UIScrollView Scrollable Content Size Ambiguity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19036228/uiscrollview-scrollable-content-size-ambiguity)