# scroll view constraint in xcode 11

Tags: xcode, constraints, xcode11

How to add constraint in xcode 11 there is two new option available when i update xcode to xcode 11

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the answer after one hour spend. You can use scrollview like old scrollview when you give a constraints to your scrollview that time select scrollview from the options.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can deselect this option and use scroll view like old version

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Basically here **frameLayoutGuide** is an alias for ScrollView frame and **contentLayoutGuide** is an alias for content size. You can skip their use and position your scroll view content just like you use to before. If you want to use Layout guides, pin your contentView to **contentLayoutGuide** (leading, trailing, top, bottom constraints) and set your positioning constraints (centre horizontally or vertically) to **frameLayoutGuide**. Below is the image that shows content view positioned using layout guides.

[image: content view positioned inside scroll view]

If you want to follow old way of positioning [refer this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19036228/uiscrollview-scrollable-content-size-ambiguity).