# Xcode 11 scrollView constraints issue inside another scrollView

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, constraints, scrollview, xcode11

After Xcode 11, I can not set the UIScrollView constraint inside another UIScrollView.

I have a parent scrollView & a child scrollView.

parent scrollView is the parent of all elements in the page & can scroll vertical if the contents height gets taller than the screen.

On very top of contents, I have a horizontal photo slider (I use Auk) which is another scrollView.

Before the Xcode 11, I set the constraints like this & there was no problem:

For the parent scrollView:

- connect top, bottom, left, right constraint to the superView(safe area)
- equal the with of parentScrollView to the superView(view) to block horizontal scroll

For the child scrollView:

- connect top, bottom, left, right constraint to the superView(parent scrollView)
- equal the with of childScrollView to the superView(parentScrollView)
- setAspectRation to 16:9 (for adjusting the height of child scrollView relative to its width)

But I get ambiguous height & width error on interfaceBuilder for the child scrollView

[image]

Also I turned off the 'Content Layout Guide' for both scrollViews

I saw this famous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19036228/uiscrollview-scrollable-content-size-ambiguity) but it did not helped as well.

The app runs perfect as I expected, but there are some warnings on the console which I don't like to see...

In my opinion, most of the similar questions on Stack Overflow are about elements in scrollView, mine is for Xcode 11+ & scrollView inside scrollView.

I added the demo project, you can download it [from here](https://gofile.io/?c=20n7V6).

Comment: give fixed height to the inner scrollview, or turn off its scrolling property.

Comment: @dahiya_boy tried it & its the same.

Comment: Show your exact expected ui then and only i could say anything.

Comment: @dahiya_boy I added a demo project & updated the answer.