# Scroll view that contains a stack view (and/or a content view) not working expectedly

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, autolayout, uistackview

I want to have a scroll view that displays all of my things in a stack view vertically.

1. First, I created a view named `contentView` within the scroll view which contains the stack view, which means I now have `view` -> `scrollView` -> `contentView` -> `stackView`.
2. I set the content view's leading, trailing, top and bottom anchors to be equal to those constraints of the scroll views content layout guide.
3. I made the width of the content view the same as the width of the scroll views frame layout guide.
4. I made the stack view's leading, trailing, top and bottom anchors to be equal to the content view's corresponding anchors.

[image]

This doesn't scroll.

I tried following this SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43785127/10116367):

1. I got rid of the `Content Layout Guides` and applied the `contentView`'s constraints to be 0,0,0,0 to all 4 sides and center it horizontally and vertically to the scroll view.
2. In size inspector, change bottom and align center Y priority to 250.
3. Set the bottom anchor of the stack view to `view` (not the scroll view).

[image]

This only scrolls a little bit, but doesn't fully scroll the bottom.  Much of the view is just hidden outside of the screen.

I also tried getting rid of `contentView` all together and pinned my stack view to either the scroll view or to `view` directly, but none worked.

Finally, I tried this super hacky-looking solution:

```swift
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews(){
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: view.bounds.width, height: view.bounds.height+300)
}
```

but, it squishes the stack view vertically and doesn't display the content fully.

P.S. I'm adding the constraints for the stack view programmatically:

```swift
stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor).isActive = true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example that will work - see if you can figure out what you may have done differently.

Instead of using a "content view" we'll just add the stack view directly to the scroll view via code.

Here's the Storyboard layout:

[image]

Here's the source for the Storyboard, so you can examine it directly:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.Storyboard.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="16096" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" useSafeAreas="YES" colorMatched="YES" initialViewController="dVO-AO-rAX">
    <device id="retina3_5" orientation="portrait" appearance="light"/>
    <dependencies>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="16087"/>
        <capability name="Safe area layout guides" minToolsVersion="9.0"/>
        <capability name="documents saved in the Xcode 8 format" minToolsVersion="8.0"/>
    </dependencies>
    <scenes>
        <!--Kevvv View Controller-->
        <scene sceneID="e7x-2X-Pdg">
            <objects>
                <viewController id="dVO-AO-rAX" customClass="KevvvViewController" customModule="MiniScratch" customModuleProvider="target" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="ZMq-2S-yNo">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="320" height="480"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                        <subviews>
                            <scrollView clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" ambiguous="YES" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="bEj-BB-5lU">
                                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="44" width="320" height="402"/>
                                <viewLayoutGuide key="contentLayoutGuide" id="VmC-Gj-CCr"/>
                                <viewLayoutGuide key="frameLayoutGuide" id="HBJ-Ua-m26"/>
                            </scrollView>
                        </subviews>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" systemColor="systemBackgroundColor" cocoaTouchSystemColor="whiteColor"/>
                        <constraints>
                            <constraint firstItem="bEj-BB-5lU" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="goZ-oS-cQl" secondAttribute="leading" id="Jwq-Tg-wRK"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="goZ-oS-cQl" firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="bEj-BB-5lU" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="34" id="bHJ-DL-1xi"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="bEj-BB-5lU" firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="goZ-oS-cQl" secondAttribute="trailing" id="gIL-OY-ENf"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="bEj-BB-5lU" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="goZ-oS-cQl" secondAttribute="top" constant="44" id="zAh-qk-82E"/>
                        </constraints>
                        <viewLayoutGuide key="safeArea" id="goZ-oS-cQl"/>
                    </view>
                    <connections>
                        <outlet property="scrollView" destination="bEj-BB-5lU" id="jYI-Wh-d6w"/>
                    </connections>
                </viewController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="ieG-NN-t0K" userLabel="First Responder" customClass="UIResponder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="136.875" y="105"/>
        </scene>
    </scenes>
</document>
```

And here's example code that will add a stack view to the scroll view, add 40 labels to the stack view, and then properly constrain the stack view to the scroll view:

```
class KevvvViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var scrollView: UIScrollView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let stack = UIStackView()
        stack.axis = .vertical
        stack.spacing = 12
        
        stack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        scrollView.addSubview(stack)
        
        for i in 1...40 {
            let v = UILabel()
            v.backgroundColor = .yellow
            v.text = "Label \(i)"
            stack.addArrangedSubview(v)
        }

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            stack.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.contentLayoutGuide.topAnchor),
            stack.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.contentLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor),
            stack.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.contentLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor),
            stack.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.contentLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor),
            
            stack.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.frameLayoutGuide.widthAnchor),
        ])
        
        // to make it easy to see the scroll view frame
        scrollView.backgroundColor = .cyan
    }
    
}
```

Result, after scrolling down to the 17th label (iPhone 8):

[image]

Comment: Why do people give mixed advice on `contentLayoutGuide`? When do we need it and when do we not? I've seen some people advice to get ride of `contentLayoutGuide` for this very use case.

Comment: @Kevvv - are you asking about `contentLayoutGuide`? Or do you really mean *adding your own "content view"*?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you only need a `UIScrollView` and a `UIStackView` like that:

[image]

Both `UIScrollView` and `UIStackView` have set the top, bottom, leading and trailing constraints to their respective superviews. The only difference is the last constraint, between the `UIStackView`'s width and the `Safe Area` width. (this depends on what width do you want the `UIStackView` to have)

You may also need to set `UIStackView`'s `Distribution` to something like `Equal Spacing` to make sure that always expands depending on its content.

Also, add something in the `UIStackView` so that the auto layout stops complaining. (avoid red constraints on the interface builder)

Give it a shot.

Comment: As I mentioned it in my question, I've tried this way as well. Tried pinning the stack view directly to either the view or the scroll view without the content view.

Comment: @Kevvv yes, but your constraints are different. You had constraints with centerY and centerX and you do not have the last constraint that I mention, between the `UIStackView` width and the `Safe Area` width.