# UIScrollView with UIStackView which resizes to fullfill the screen height

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uistackview, safearea

No code because everything is placed in xib.

Structure: `UIScrollView` contains `UIView` ([UIScrollView Scrollable Content Size Ambiguity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19036228/uiscrollview-scrollable-content-size-ambiguity)) which contains `UIStackView` which contains a list of subviews. All the `UIStackView` subviews have fixed height except of one which has "minimal height" only and I need to stretch this view to make `UIStackView` fullfilling all available height if necessary. If `UIStackView` is very big then `UIScrollView` should scroll `UIStackView`.

Tried a lot of combinations but the only view which should stretch or collapse has unpredictable height. In better case it works as expected but `UIScrollView` content fully ignores safe area (becomes larger than expected).

Did somebody faced this problem?

**Edited**

It is a view controller inside xib, loading/presenting modally.
[A link to xib](https://uploadnow.io/f/sWNRy03)

Comment: If you are sure your changes have "fixed" your issue, great. But, if you're looking for *maybe a better solution* we need more information. Is your `xib` a *view controller*? or a *view*? How are you loading/displaying it? Show us a screen-cap of your layout, making sure to expand all of the constraints so we can see what you're doing.

Comment: @DonMag edited question and even added an original xib (where problem wasn't solved)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a weird solution:

- disable safe area for the root view
- enable safe area for scroll view (which is is inserted directly in the root view)
- setup constraints like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19036228/uiscrollview-scrollable-content-size-ambiguity) (leading, trailing, top, bottom, equal width, equal height with low priority) with one difference - **scroll view's root view height should be equal not to superview height but to safe area height**

But maybe someone can suggest a better solution