# Add UIScrollView which fulfills superview and add its content which fulfills everything but safe area

Tags: uiscrollview, scrollable, contentsize, intrinsic-content-size, safearea

In short words I want achieve the following:
[image]

Content is shown behind bottom safe area but user can scroll it.
This implemented with `UITableView` which has such behavior by default but I need to do that with `UIScrollView` with subviews.

As I understand `UIScrollView` should fulfills its superview. This `UIScrollView` contains "content view" which fulfills its superview too. And this "content view" contains for example `UIStackView` with constraints (it is just as example - I set constraints in XIB):

```
stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualTo: stackView.superview!.bottomAnchor)
        stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualTo: scrollView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor)
```

But after these actions scrolling becomes broken.

Tried to change `contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior` but it works strange and `UIScrollView`'s `contentSize` is stretched even when there is enough space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to constrain the scroll view's "content" to the scroll view's `Content Layout Guide`

Take a look at this example ... it adds a "full-view" scroll view, adds a vertical stack view to the scroll view and then adds 10 image views to the stack view:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        title = "Wizard"
        
        let scrollView = UIScrollView()
        let stackView = UIStackView()
        
        stackView.axis = .vertical
        stackView.spacing = 8
        
        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        scrollView.addSubview(stackView)
        view.addSubview(scrollView)
        
        let cg = scrollView.contentLayoutGuide
        let fg = scrollView.frameLayoutGuide
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            // constrain all 4 sides of scroll view to view
            scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
            scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
            scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),

            // constrain all 4 sides of stack view to scroll view's Content Layout Guide
            stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cg.topAnchor),
            stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cg.leadingAnchor),
            stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cg.trailingAnchor),
            stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cg.bottomAnchor),

            // constrain stack view width to scroll view's Frame Layout Guide width
            stackView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: fg.widthAnchor),
            
        ])
        
        // generate 10 image views with images and add to the stack view
        for i in 0..<10 {
            let img = genImage(sz: .init(width: 200.0, height: 200.0), num: i)
            let v = UIImageView(image: img)
            v.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200.0).isActive = true
            stackView.addArrangedSubview(v)
        }
        
    }
    
    func genImage(sz: CGSize, num: Int) -> UIImage {
        let colors: [UIColor] = [
            .systemRed, .systemGreen, .systemBlue,
            .cyan, .green, .yellow,
        ]
        
        let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: sz)
        guard let nImg = UIImage(systemName: "\(num).circle.fill") else { fatalError() }
        let img = renderer.image { ctx in
            colors[num % colors.count].setFill()
            ctx.fill(.init(origin: .zero, size: sz))
            nImg.draw(in: .init(origin: .zero, size: sz))
        }
        
        return img
    }

}
```

Looks like this:

[image]

and after scrolling a bit:

[image]

and scrolled all the way to the bottom:

[image]

---

**Edit** - *in response to comments...*

A couple problems with your XIB approach.

***Issue One***: the *"ambigious scrollable height"* has nothing to do with the fact that you're working with a XIB instead of Storyboard.

Suppose we setup a view controller like this:

[image]

We see the Red missing/ambiguous constraints error indicator.

A `UIView` has no **size** until we've given it a size. If we run the app like that, we see this:

[image]

Pink scroll view, but no sign of the Blue "content" view.

Now, as the **Developer**, I know that at run-time I'm going to add one or more views (such as a stack view with some big labels) to that Blue view - with proper constraints - to get my desired UI:

[image]

[image]

and it works fine.

When using Storyboard / Interface Builder to layout the views, **I** know what I'm going to do at run-time, but **IB** doesn't.

This is an IB error/warning that we *could* safely ignore ... but, since we generally don't want to ignore things, the solution is to give that Blue "content" view an **Intrinsic Content Size Placeholder**.

Find this near the bottom of the Size Inspector pane:

[image]

and change it:

[image]

to get this:

[image]

Now, without any other changes to the interface, the Red indicator is gone:

[image]

The actual Width and Height values you use are irrelevant ... they simply tell IB that we know what we're doing.

***Issue Two***: trying to get the scroll view to fill the entire screen - including the safe-areas - while *also* getting the scroll view's content to respect the safe-areas:

[image]

That behavior is only automatic if the **scroll view is the first subview of the controller's view.**

If you create a View XIB and add a scroll view to it, you have to "extract" the scroll view at run-time.

An easier approach is to create an **Empty** XIB, and add a `UIScrollView` as its "base" view.

I put up a project at https://github.com/DonMag/Sample20231206 that you can take a look at.

Comment: thanks, I combined with my code and it works. The only question I have is which constraints do you recommend to setup in xib to avoid "ambigious scrollable height"? Previosly I did it by disabling `Content Layout Guides`

Comment: @Gargo - tough to say, without seeing your XIB

Comment: previously I added `UIScrollView`, disabled its "Content Layout Guides" and add constraints to all its sides. By default it is 0 to all safe area sides. Then I insert `UIView` into `UIScrollView` and again add constraints to all the sides. By default it is 0 but to all superview sides. To resolve appearing errors I add constraints `view.centerX == scrollView.centerX` and `view.centerY == scrollView.centerY` (the last one is with 250 priority). In code it is similar to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53859921/805701 but scrollView is bound to safe area and I use centerY instead of height

Comment: @Gargo - ***most likely*** your "content view" has no height defined... but again, tough to say without seeing your xib. Are you creating a xib with a view, and adding a scroll view to that view? Or, are you creating an Empty xib, and adding a scroll view as its "base" view? If you create a simple example xib and post it (either as a file, or post its source somewhere like PasteBin.com) I can take a look at it.

Comment: a link to xib files: https://file.io/iY8gKxHMdM5E

Comment: @Gargo - "file deleted" at that link?

Comment: sorry, silly file sharing service "deletes files after 1 download". Reuploaded: https://filetransfer.io/data-package/9AD3X8Ql#link

Comment: @Gargo - see the **Edit** to my answer.