# ScrollView disable on Device Orientation

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, storyboard

I am using ScrollView on the screen while in portrait mode. When I change the orientation, can I disable the scrolling?
ScrollView can be disabled from the storyboard or it needs to be solved using methods.
I have tried size class to manage the disable and enable the scrolling.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UIScrollView disable scrolling while rotating on iPhone/iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4123991/uiscrollview-disable-scrolling-while-rotating-on-iphone-ipad)

Answer (score 0):

These days, the concept of Portrait or Landscape has fallen out of favor. Your app may be running in multi-tasking mode on an iPad, for example, and could be "tall and narrow" even though the **device** is being held in "landscape" orientation.

It seems a little odd that you'd want to disable scrolling, but assuming that is your design goal -- you can set it in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    
    // disable scrolling if view's width is greater than its height
    scrollView.isScrollEnabled = view.frame.height > view.frame.width
}
```